# Monitor flickering after standby mode Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, xrandr

My ultra book Dell Latitude E7450 is mounted on top of docker station. From docker I send video signal via 2 DVI outputs to two external monitors. One of my external monitors starts flickering after standby mode. Strange thing is that after restarting the Ubuntu it seems to work normally. Any suggestion how to fix flickering external monitor?

```
$xrandr

eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     48.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+29 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1-2 connected 1080x1920+3840+29 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```